# An Altered List II

Tags: knowledge, wordplay

Yep, this is a series now.
The following list of items has been altered. They all use some form of wordplay originating from the item, with some being very literal and straightforward, while others are obscure and challenging. You need not solve all of the items (but congrats if you do!), the answer is the category of the original items. Good luck!

- A solar eclipse
- 6 Indy 500's
- Our saviour the half-wax bird
- Orcs, goblins, drow, and ogres
- A tornado siren
- A stolen piece of wood
- /give @s minecraft_moon 1
- Strange smears reappearing
- LAVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
- The laws of the sea
- Doomfist's ultimate move
- The labyrinth guardian (and us!)

Hint:

> Related to an answer below, both Lord of the Rings and The Hobbit fit into the category. However, they are not part of the list above.

Hint 2:

> Brick by brick, someone's got to be piecing this together...

Hint 3:

> Three more items have been added to the list.

[Full Series](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=user%3A75335%20title%3A%22An%20Altered%20List%22%20is%3Aq)

Comment: Oh I think I know.... Just up my alley!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a disguised list of:

> **[LEGO board games](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamefamily/2909/series-lego-games)**. This makes sense of Hint 2's mention of 'Brick by brick'.

The clues should be interpreted as follows:

A solar eclipse

> [Sunblock](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/89926/sunblock) (in an eclipse, the *sun* is *blocked*, usually by the moon)

6 Indy 500's

> [Race 3000](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/46744/race-3000) (since the [Indianapolis 500](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indianapolis_500) is a *race*, and $3000 = 6*500$)

Our saviour the half-wax bird

> This clues the [Heroica](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgamefamily/9918/series-lego-heroica) series of board games: 'saviour' = '**HERO**', 'half-wax bird' = half of [**ICA**rus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icarus), the figure from Greek mythology who flew too close to the sun on wings of wax.

Orcs, goblins, drow, and ogres

> [Monster 4](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/46746/monster-4) - a list of 4 monsters!

A tornado siren

> [City Alarm](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/116978/city-alarm) i.e. something that might sound in the event of an emergency...

A stolen piece of wood

> [Pirate Plank](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/63900/pirate-plank) ('stolen' = 'pirate', 'piece of wood' = 'plank')

/give @s minecraft_moon 1

> [Lunar Command](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/41834/lunar-command) (a command line relating to the moon)

Strange smears reappearing

> [Ramses Return](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/89927/ramses-return) - this is cryptic wordplay: SMEARS is an anagram of RAMSES, and 'reappearing' is a synonym of 'return'.

LAVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

> Initially, I thought this one was most likely to be [Magma Monster](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/63899/magma-monster), since "LAVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA!" sounds like it could be the roar of such a beast. However, I also considered it might somehow clue '[Lava Dragon](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/46745/lava-dragon)' and I really like @Amoz's suggestion that this is "*Lava draggin' (dragging)*", extending the word length in a cryptic way :)

The laws of the sea

> [Pirate Code](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/46743/pirate-code) (see *Pirates of the Caribbean* if in any doubt here...)

Doomfist's ultimate move

> [Meteor Strike](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/80972/meteor-strike) - in *Overwatch*, the character [Doomfist](https://overwatch.fandom.com/wiki/Doomfist) has a special move by this name...

The labyrinth guardian (and us!)

> [Minotaurus](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/41835/minotaurus) (since the minotaur guarded the [Labyrinth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Labyrinth) in Greek myth) - this was the clue which gave the theme away to me, as I have this game in my collection!

Also, re the first Hint:

> There is also a LEGO game called '[Lord of the Rings: The Battle of Helm's Deep](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/145306/lord-rings-battle-helms-deep)' - as well as LEGO video games themed around both *Lord of the Rings* and *The Hobbit* - which makes the initial incorrect answer by @Vir (a *Lord of the Rings* theme) an uncanny coincidence!

Comment: So I shouldn't have spent 12 mins typing this up... nice beat

Comment: Very very close finish. Nice job!
rot13(Urebvpn jnf nabgure pelcgvp-glcr pyhr, jvgu UREB+VPN(-ehf)), but ambiguity is kept on purpose.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if this is right, then as a

> Lego fanatic and online seller, I probably had an unfair advantage. With the latest hints, I recognized Minotaur+Us as Minotaurus, the Lego board game. From there, it was a matter of matching up the rest and pleasantly finding such an endeavor was possible.  So this is a list of LEGO BOARD GAMES!

A solar eclipse

> Sunblock

6 Indy 500's

> Race 3000

Our saviour the half-wax bird

> ? probably Mini-taurus, else maybe Minotaurus or Legends of Chima or one of the random hero games

Orcs, goblins, drow, and ogres

> Monster 4

A tornado siren

> Lego City Alarm

A stolen piece of wood

> Pirate Plank

/give @s minecraft_moon 1

> Lunar Command

Strange smears reappearing

> ? Ramses Return, if 'Ramses' clues 'strange smears' (anagram)

LAVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

> Lava Dragon (lava draggin')

The laws of the sea

> Pirate Code

Doomfist's ultimate move

> I don't know anything about Doomfist but there are a few obvious options

The labyrinth guardian (and us!)

> Minotaurus (Minotaur+Us)

Comment: Looks like I just pipped you to an answer by a few minutes, sorry! :) However, I like your lava suggestion better than mine - the "draggin'" wordplay is neat.